# Unable to connect to Maven Central Repository within organization due to Firewall, Maven does not connect to internal URL and fails in simple project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

I am working inside an organization and the firewall settings donot allow download of jars from Maven Central repository. Instead the organization has created an internal repository https://internalurl  that exactly mirrors the directory or  package structure of the Maven central repository

So In my $HOME.m2\settings.xml I have put the following entries so that the internalurl is used by Maven build instead of Maven Central repository

```
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
<mirrors>
<mirror>
<id>central-proxy</id>
<name>Local proxy of central repo</name>
<url>https://internalurl</url>
<mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
</mirrors>
</settings>
```

Next I am trying to create a simple "Maven Web Project" on Eclipse by selecting Archetype  "maven-archetype-webapp" version 1.0 from GroupId org.apache.maven.archetypes
But once I enter  the Project GroupId, ArtifactId and click Finish I get the following error
could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 from any of the configured repositories

```
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from https://internalurl  was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central-proxy has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact
```

When I go to our internal Maven  Repository site, and drill down to the below URL and the package structure,  I can see that the maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0  is present
If I goto  https://internalurl/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-webapp/1.0
I can see the following 2 files

maven-archetype-webapp-1.0.jar
maven-archetype-webapp-1.0.pom

So why is Eclipse reporting the ERROR and not creating the project ?
Please Help.

thanks

Comment: First if you are inside an org an using a repository manager you should use `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` instead of something else so anything will be redirected to the given URL....What kind of repository manager do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You must change your setting like below.

```
<mirror>
<id>central-proxy</id>
<name>Local proxy of central repo</name>
<url>https://internalurl</url>
<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

According to the document below, Because `<mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>` means to point to a mirror of the Maven central repository.

[Maven Settings Reference - Mirrors](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Mirrors)

[Maven Mirrors Guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html)

Comment: Hi Changuk like you mentioned I changed <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf> to <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>    in settings.xml. But even after that I get the same error . So you can see from the error message it is connecting to the Internal repository  https://internalurl  but still not able to find the jar even though it exists in https://internalurl/org/apache/maven/archetypes/maven-archetype-webapp/1.0 .. 
The internal repository used by the organization is Artifactory